# Automation Tool for Native Windows Application?

Tags: windows, automation

I have an application running on a windows server which does not have API access or command line access. In other words you have to start the application and manually interact with it to use it.

I have to enter in an account number and a few more click and the application  spits out a .zip of files. It is a completely manual process. The problem is that I have to do this proximity **7,000** times.

Is there any tool that can

1. take file that contains a list of paraments
2. record my clicks etc and substitute in the info from the file so that I can automate the 7K queries / exports that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with autohotkey, It's a scripting language specifically for this type of problem.   I have not used it extensively, but from what people have told me, it would allow you to script this process.

Answer (score 1):

[Gordon's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/80733/76723) is what I would recommend as well, but that probably only answers #1 of OP's request.

For the #2 use it with [MACRO RECORDER in AutoHotKey](https://github.com/adegard/AHK_SCRIPTS)